# Changes in d3 (Data-Driven Documents)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I started learning D3 from the book "Getting started with D3" by Mike Devar published in 2012. I have to make several D3 examples for my college project so I thought this would be a good place to start since I already went over the book 3 years ago. However, I downloaded the latest D3 version (4.6.0), and I noticed some of the examples in the book don't work any longer.

I tested the following example with both the newest version, and the version that was included with the examples from the book. It works with the old version (4.5.1), but not the new one, and since I can't seem to find any site that would list the changes in versions, can someone point out which parts of the code have to be changed so the example will work with the latest version?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <script>
        function draw(data) {
            "use strict";

            var margin = 50,
                width = 700,
                height = 300,
                x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.collision_with_injury}),
                y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.dist_between_fail});

            var x_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .range([margin, width-margin])
                            .domain(x_extent);

            var y_scale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .range([height-margin, margin])
                            .domain(y_extent);

            d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
              .selectAll("circle")
              .data(data)
              .enter()
              .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d){return x_scale(d.collision_with_injury)})
                .attr("cy", function(d){return y_scale(d.dist_between_fail)})
                .attr("r", 5);
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        d3.json('data/bus_perf.json', draw);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much to change in your code to make it work with d3 v4 - latest version.

I changed `d3.scale.linear` to `d3.scaleLinear` in both instances and thats it. Do check out the new documentation for more info. There is a decent amount of changes in terms of syntax from v3 to v4.

Documentation is here - https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/0exp8x68/

Answer (score 1):

I think your best chance is [here](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md). It's quite a read though (you can see the effort that was put there, kudos to Mike Bostock).

If you work with scales and axes, the main changes you'll face are:

- there is no `scale`object anymore, they all goo like `d3.scaleLinear`, `d3.scaleOrdinal`, etc.
- there is no `svg` object anymore, generators reside on the `d3` object: `d3.line()`
- axes are now separated, i.e. `d3.axisBottom()`, `d3.axisLeft()`, etc.

This is a very, very brief summary, but I hop it can get you going